# Refactor foreach with multilevel array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I'm currently returning results from a sql statement in an array like so:

```
$results = [];

    foreach($promotionTool as $p){
        $results[] = $p;
    }

    return $results;
```

Which my console shows in an object with this structure:

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
    0:
        codeID: "41"
        code: "123ABC"
        rule_type: "Category"
        attribute_type: "identifier"
        attribute_title: "category number"
        attribute_value: "234"
    1:
        codeID: "41"
        code: "123ABC"
        rule_type: "Category"
        attribute_type: "amount"
        attribute_title: "percent"
        attribute_value: "25"
```

This is showing the data I expect but I'm a little bit lost on how to restructure this so that I can group on certain levels and finally return only an array of the attributes like so:

```
    codeID
        code
            rule_type
                array(
                    0:
                        attribute_type: "identifier"
                        attribute_title: "category number"
                        attribute_value: "234"
                    1:
                        attribute_type: "amount"
                        attribute_title: "percent"
                        attribute_value: "25"   
                )
```

How would I refactor my foreach to group at multiple levels in that way?

Comment: So you basically want to sort of "group" the array and exclude the keys with equal values? What if there's another entry with: 
`codeID: "42"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is what you are looking for:

```
<?php

$input = [
    [
        'codeID' => "41",
        'code' => "123ABC",
        'rule_type' => "Category",
        'attribute_type' => "identifier",
        'attribute_title' => "category number",
        'attribute_value' => "234"
    ], 
    [
        'codeID' => "41",
        'code' => "123ABC",
        'rule_type' => "Category",
        'attribute_type' => "amount",
        'attribute_title' => "percent",
        'attribute_value' => "25"
    ]
];


$output = [];
array_walk($input, function ($e) use (&$output) {
    $output[$e['codeID']][$e['code']][$e['rule_type']][] = [
        'attribute_type' => $e['attribute_type'],
        'attribute_title' => $e['attribute_title'],
        'attribute_value' => $e['attribute_value']
    ];
});

print_r($output);
```

This could be a variant easier to read:

```
array_walk($input, function ($e) use (&$output) {
    $codeID = &$e['codeID'];
    $code = &$e['code'];
    $rule_type = &$e['rule_type'];

    $output[$codeID][$code][$rule_type][] = [
        'attribute_type' => $e['attribute_type'],
        'attribute_title' => $e['attribute_title'],
        'attribute_value' => $e['attribute_value']
    ];
});
```

The output obviously is:

```
Array
(
    [41] => Array
        (
            [123ABC] => Array
                (
                    [Category] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [attribute_type] => identifier
                                    [attribute_title] => category number
                                    [attribute_value] => 234
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [attribute_type] => amount
                                    [attribute_title] => percent
                                    [attribute_value] => 25
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: One quick question: This gives the first three levels of codeID, code, and rule_type as their values, which is correct. But how can I give each of those a level title so it would say [codeID] => 41, [code] => 123ABC, etc.

Comment: Everything is possible, sure, but this is not trivial, since you cannot have an element of an array entry have _two_ values, the number _and_ the array you want. If you can tell how exactly the result should look like it is no difficult task to create that. But I do not see an obvious solution for that.